# Json adding backslash in Volley Response called in a Dialogue Fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

In my php it produce a Json like below and this working fine when I testing in Postman

```
{"comment_id":8,"commenter_username":"abc","profile_image_path":abc/abc/abc.jpg","comment_body":"adssadasdasdaa","comment_created_at":"2017-03-21 13:03:40"},
```

But when it parse to volley,it become like this

```
{"comment":[{"comment_created_at":"2017-03-21 13:03:40","comment_id":8,"comment_body":"adssadasdasdaa","commenter_username":"abc","profile_image_path":"http:\/\/abc\/def\/v1\/abc\/defaultmale.jpg"}
```

I found many posts in Stackoverflow,so I tried this,which is working well in other activity.

```
json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Here come in my Dialog Fragment,I made Volley Request,the Json adding backslashes in the URL.

**Here is my code in Dialog Fragment**,which I think is same like the other Activity.

```
private void fetchCommentOfPost(int post_id){


    // making fresh volley request and getting json
    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            AppConfig.URL_GET_COMMENT + post_id, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            VolleyLog.d(AppController.TAG, "VolleyResponse: " + response.toString());
            Log.d("responseGet",response.toString());
            parseJsonFeed(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(AppController.TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        }
    }) {
        //adding header to authenticate
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return  headers;
        }
    };

    // Adding request to volley request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

}
```

Can somebody please tell me how to get rid the backslashes in Json accept what i tried?Cause I totally have no idea.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing to worry about! If you wanna load images in `imageview`, Simple User `Glide` image loading library.. everything goes fine.

Comment: @really??no need to worry about it??

Comment: yeah `Glide` will handle that, totally!!

Comment: it will be nice..cause I use Glide as well